# If $ \omega $ is imaginary cube root of 1, then $(1+\omega-\omega^2)^7 = $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex number system and I want the value of $ (1+\omega-\omega^2)^7 $ . Where $ \omega $ is cube root of unity.

(Cube roots of unity: $ 1, e^{±i\frac{2\pi}{3}} $ )

I want to simply get the value of the expression in easy way.

Comment: There are no imaginary cube roots of unity.

Comment: Use the fact that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$. Do you see why that must hold?

Comment: @mrf To some (many) users *imaginary number* = *non-real complex number*, and *pure imaginary* = *a complex number with real part zero*. This may not be ideal, but many people talk like that.

Comment: @Jyrki Then what is ideal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ when $\omega$ is a cube root of unity $\neq 1$. Using this fact, we have, $$(1+\omega-\omega^2)^7=((1+\omega+\omega^2)-2\omega^2)^7=(-2\omega^2)^7=-128\omega^{14}=-128(\omega^3)^4\omega^2=-128\omega^2$$

Answer (score 1):

1+$\omega$ +$\omega^2$ = 0 (this holds since $\omega^3$=1 => $\omega^3$-1=0 => ($\omega$ -1)(1+$\omega$ +$\omega^2$)=0
 and here $\omega$ $\neq$ 1 )

This gives:
1+$\omega$ =-$\omega^2$

Substitute it in $(1+ω−\omega^2)^7$,
you get

$-2\times(\omega^2)^7$= $(-2)^7$*$\omega^14$=$-128\times\omega^2$

where ω is cube root of unity

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity:

$$(x^n-1)=(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})$$

which is valid for complex numbers as well, you see that when $\omega$ is a root of unity other than $1$, i.e. $w^n=1$ but $w \neq 1$, we have $1+\omega+\cdots+\omega^{n-1}=0$

Now use this result for $n=3$, and note that

$$(1+\omega-\omega^2)^7=(1+\omega+\omega^2-2\omega^2)^7=(-2\omega^2)^7=-128w^{14}=-128(\omega^{12}\cdot\omega^2)=-128\omega^2$$